# How can you compare strings in android with greater than

Tags: java, android, compare

I was wondering if there is a way to compare strings in android with greater than or >.

Lets say I have this:

```
String numbers = number.getText().toString();
if (numbers.equals("9")){
output.setText("50");}
```

so if you enter 9 in the number EditText field the output TextView will display 50.
I have quite a few different numbers that will then = a different number but what can I do   if I want 10,11,12,13,etc to = 100?

Is there a way to do this by using something like this?

```
if (numbers.equals("9"++))
```

or is there some kind of wildcard in android like

```
if (numbers.equals("1"+"*"))
```

i know if i replace the * with zero it will be 10 so if this is possible I could make  one for 1, one for 2, one for 3, etc. and this would still save me so much code.
If this is not possible let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert the String to a number first.  Something like this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
if (number > 9)
{
    output.setText("50");
}
```

If the String is not guaranteed to be a valid integer you'll have to handle `NumberFormatException` too.

Comment: Thanks alot! I was wondering how to do that and i had tried a few different things with no success. This makes the rest of it so much simpler. At one point i have a calculate button that adds two outputs together but i was using this mess to accomplish it: int result = (int) (new Double(output1.getText().toString()) + new Double(output2.getText().toString())); answer.setText(""+result); but after i change this as long as I have android:numeric="decimal" in my xml file for the edittext that should work without issues right?

Comment: @Daniel If you want fractional numbers instead of integers, you should use Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this has saved me alot of time.

Comment: Now I can get the result displayed properly but when I delete both of the numbers entered it force closes. It works if its just one. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel Use "adb logcat" to see what exception is being thrown to cause the force close.  Probably a NumberFormatException from attempting to parse an empty string.  You'll have to surround the call with try/catch.

Comment: You were exactly right, I'm working on that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't use

```
Integer.valueOf("9");
```

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to do this.