# Applying and Creating Multiple Views For GridViewLayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

Im attempting to add two different views to the `GridviewLayoutManager` using a custom adapter.

However, I cant seem to reference the headerview correctly. When the `onbindViewHolder` is called it is expecting a "ViewHolder" response, however i really want to reference the HeaderView i crated

Because I cant access the correct view, I also cant reference the `TextView` within the XML layout I am calling.

here is my customer adaptor class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ElementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mDatamap;

public Context context;

    private static final int VIEW_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_NORMAL = 1;

    private View headerView;
    private int datasetSize;

    public class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView headertext;

        public HeaderHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            headertext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headertext);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public ImageView imgImage;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            imgImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }

    }

    public ElementsAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset, ArrayList<Integer> myDatamap) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        myDatamap = mDatamap;
    }


      @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isHeader(position) == 1 ? VIEW_HEADER : VIEW_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_HEADER) {
            // create a new view
            View sub_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);

            Context context = sub_view.getContext();

            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(sub_view);

            return vh;


//            return new HeaderViewHolder(headerView);

        } else {
            // create a new view
            View sub_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, parent, false);

            context = sub_view.getContext();

            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(sub_view);

            return vh;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (isHeader(position) == 1) {

            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            final String name = mDataset.get(position);

//        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
            viewHolder.headertext.setText(name);

        } else {

    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = mDataset.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.500kgiveaway.co.uk/"+name).resize(200,200).into(viewHolder.imgImage);

//        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(name);

    viewHolder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
        //remove(name);
    }
    }

    );

    viewHolder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: "+mDataset.get(position));
}

        //ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        //holder.textView.setText("Position " + (position - 1));
    }

    public int isHeader(int position) {
        return mDatamap.get(position) ==1 ? 1:0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `isHeader()` method will always return 0, since you compare a String with a integer. I assume you would like want to check the position of the current item to be 1.

Try this code instead:

```
public boolean isHeader(int position) {
    return position == 1;
}
```

Then replace

```
if (isHeader(position) == 1)...
```

with

```
if (isHeader(position))...
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

The above was intended. Sorry.
In the class definition `ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder` is inserted as the ViewHolder type. This works for the normal

```
ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

but not for

```
ElementsAdapter.HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

since it doesn't extend ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder.

You should therfore specify `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` instead as a generic type to support both of your types.

Comment: i wanted this to lookup the value in the MyDataMap array at position (position). If this == 1 then i wanted to return 1, if not then i wanted to return 0

Comment: Then you will want to convert the String to an int first, to be able to comare them, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4092190/4983239 . Or you could use a `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of a `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: sorry my variable naming could be confusing. I have myDataSet which stores the data and myDataMap which denotes the type of view that should be displayed. Do you have any ideas on how i create a second view? at which point i could test the rest of the code

Comment: changed public class ElementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder>  to public class ElementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> but i get  an error because the onBindViewHolder requests a ViewHolder. When i change this to RecyclerView.ViewHolder i loose the ability to reference the objects within the view

Comment: here is the error- class "elementsAdapter" must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onBindViewHolder(VH, int) in 'Adapter'

Comment: What if you cast the ViewHolder to the already expected sub-type? `HeaderView hv = (HeaderView) generic_viewholder` for example.