# How to compare String from edittext not less than 10 in android?

Tags: android

I have an edit text in which user enters an amount and I want to compare that amount not less than 10, if found less than 10 then I want to show toast message. How can I do that?

```
m_szAmount = m_InputAmount.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (m_szAmount.equals(10)) {
                        m_InputAmount.setError("Please enter the amount between Rs. 10 and Rs. 1100");

                    } else {
                        confirmationDialog();
                    }
```

Comment: `int m_szAmount = Integer.parseInt(m_InputAmount.getText().toString().trim());`

I hope you know how to compare integers.

Comment: first get text from editext and then convert/parse it to int then compare whether the entered text is less or = 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you compare strings in android with greater than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092161/how-can-you-compare-strings-in-android-with-greater-than)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
m_szAmount = m_InputAmount.getText().toString().trim();

if (Integer.valueOf(m_szAmount) <= 10){
    m_InputAmount.setError("Please enter the amount between Rs. 10 and Rs. 1100");

} else {
    confirmationDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
m_szAmount = m_InputAmount.getText().toString().trim();
 try
 {
                if (Integer.parseInt(m_szAmount)>10) {
                    m_InputAmount.setError("Please enter the amount between Rs. 10 and Rs. 1100");

                } else {
                    confirmationDialog();
                }
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
     m_InputAmount.setError("Please enter Number"); 
  }
```

if it is possible that user enter not number in your editText, it is important to use try catch while using `Integer.parseInt()` because it can raise exception if you will use it for not number string's.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
m_szAmount = Integer.parseInt(m_InputAmount.getText().toString());
if( m_szAmount <= 10)
{

//show yout Toast
}
else
{

//do your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String m_szAmount = m_InputAmount.getText().toString();
    if(m_szAmount.replace(" ","").length() > 0) {
        int inputAmount = Integer.valueOf(m_szAmount);
        if (inputAmount >= 10 ){
            m_InputAmount.setError("Please enter the amount between Rs. 10 and Rs. 1100");
            m_InputAmount.requestFocus();
        }else{
            confirmationDialog();    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(String.valueOf(s.length()) <= 10){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "your text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            };
            edit_explain.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```